# Are all four-dimensional manifolds quaternion-Kähler??

Tags: manifolds, quaternions, kahler-manifolds

Where is my error?

By definition a $4k$-dimensional manifold is quaternion-Kähler if its holonomy group is a subgroup of $(\mathrm{Sp}(k)\times\mathrm{Sp}(1))/\mathbb{Z}_2$ where $\mathrm{Sp}(1)=\mathrm{SU}(2)$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the intersection of the two factors in $\mathrm{Spin}(4k)$, namely a 2-element group.

For $k=1$ this holonomy group is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Spin}(4)$.  All orientable (spin?) four-dimensional manifolds have a holonomy group contained in this, so all four-dimensional manifolds are quaternion-Kähler.

On the other hand [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion-K%C3%A4hler_manifold) states that a quaternion-Kähler manifold is Einstein.

From all this I wrongly conclude that all four manifolds are Einstein.

Comment: (I put the kahler-manifolds tag even though quaternion-Kähler manifolds are more general, because people interested in one are likely interested in the other.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that a $\text{Sp}(1) \cdot \text{Sp}(1) = SO(4)$, and so every orientable 4-manifold is quaternion-Kähler. Wikipedia means to demand $k \geq 2$. There is a clean proof of this fact due to Salamon that only really uses the representation theory of these groups; it is reproduced in Besse, "Einstein manifolds", p. 405 (14.41).

For what it's worth, Besse also make the claim (top of p. 403 in my edition) "As we shall see, the precise analog of quaternion-Kähler manifolds in dimension 4 are Einstein self-dual manifolds..." which are also studied in depth in chapter 13 of the Besse book.

Comment: Did you mean to write "every orientable 4-manifold is quaternion-Kähler"?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Haha, yes, what a silly mistake. Thanks!

Comment: In support of your constraint k≥2: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2270040/

Comment: I consider Besse all the support I need :) It's a fantastic reference probably no matter what aspect of Riemannian geometry you're doing.

Comment: I thought the scalar curvature had to be positive?? or is that because you're including hyperkahler manifolds?